# PHP list() assign - trim before assign or any other function?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using a list() assign in PHP so I could assign array values to more variables at once.

Thing is I need to trim() the array inputs before - of course you could do a foreach on array before or after that - but is there a way to cast trim as a some kind of assignment filter - or at least trim the array inline (no external function or foreach)?

The question is more like general - can you add some filter function to a list() assigment?

**EDIT:**

For those who are looking for the "simplier" solution with foreach:

```
foreach($items as $k => $v) $item[$k] = trim($v);
list($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4) = $items;
```

Comment: No you can’t; trim() does not trim arrays, but strings. And list() is special construction, which does not allow callbacks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cannot give you an easier way than [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
list($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4) = array_map('trim', $items);
```

The "trick" here is that `array_map` will apply the function to every element of the array, and then return the modified array - which will then be used by `list`.

[Little Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/7fi-f9a)

Answer (score 1):

```
$items = array_map('trim', $items);

list($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4) = $items;
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know list does not accept a kind of filter. `array_map` could be a more direct way:

```
list($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4) = array_map('trim', $items)
```

Comment: nice, but trim has to be in '' , you re saying you want to apply constant - which is nonsense :)

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the tip.